# How to flag questions that are too specific?

Tags: support, flagging

I came across [Install new OS from dedicated server's recovery mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/562809/) in a review queue today.  It seemed to me that the question was too specific for ServerFault; it's essentially about how to use one company's dedicated server control panel.  I didn't see a "too specific" option in the question flagging options, though.  What would be the most appropriate way (if any) to flag something like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I really don't see anything too specific about this question. It does seem to be written from the standpoint of a non-professional however:

1. I'm not convinced he knows what an ISO is from the question. In terms used in the close reasons, this falls somewhere between not demonstrating minimal knowledge of the system he's using, and the "professional" qualification.
2. He bought the wrong thing from a cut-rate company and now he's trying to shove a round peg through a square hole. This really reinforces the "professional" close reason, he wandering into unknown territory without support, without a plan, and the fact that he's immediately encountering problems should be no surprise to anyone. Professionals assess their situation, procure appropriate resources to fulfill requirements, and execute - he's got none of the above.

Side note: we removed the too specific close reason as it was massively overused. It's extremely rare that I see a question that's "too specific" to that user/situation. They either have flaws enough to be closed for some other reason, or they languish unloved... but in either case I don't think its a problem worth devoting any time.

Comment: Truly unloved questions, which have a score of 0 or lower, at most one comment, and no answers, are automatically deleted after 365 days. So there's not much need to go hunting for them to kill them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the problem there is that the question is *too specific*...

The author is describing a Ubuntu-based recovery OS from which he's expected to install Elastix. I rather doubt either of those tools are specific to his hosting company, although it probably wouldn't hurt if he specified the *version* of Ubuntu he's working with.

The bigger problem with the question is... It's misleading. After all, you were mislead, right? Can't have that.

If possible, edit questions like this to clarify the intent. If that's not possible, there's an "Unclear what you're asking" flag reason...